# Bitcoin General API

Tags: api, development

I want to create an API that works for all brands of bitcoin.  Is there a way to use one general API used for all brands of bitcoins, or I must create every API for each brand?

Comment: What is a Bitcoin brand?

Comment: By brand I mean several bitcoin websites

Comment: But your API will by definition be provided by some site, so it will be a "brand" on its own?

Comment: I mean that there are lots of sites for bitcoin, so for example I want to create an application with a bitcoin API.  Should I create for every website its own API or is there a general and collective way for all bitcoin websites. Thank you

Comment: To accomplish what? What kind of API? Exchanging? Transacting? Exchange rate? Transacting? Webwallets? Analysis?

Comment: Authentication and exchanging or transacting... but there are several websites such as blockchain, freebitco, bitcointalk, coinbase etc... so when I create an API for example for transacting, is there a third party involved which might be a general API that all bitcoin websites use? I'm sorry if I am confusing you but it's the best way I can explain it.  Thank you

Comment: blockchain.info is a webwallet. bitcointalk is a forum. coinbase is an exchange. I don't understand how you can combine them. I'm voting to close this as too broad, but feel free to ask another more focussed question.

Answer (score 1):

Each exchange ("brand" as you named it) provides its own API. Those are mostly similar, allowing access to wallet, history, transaction, ... but there are often small differences (like the return value, the params to provide) wich imply to write one API wrapper per exchange.

HTH